# Obviar delimitadores en CSV con C#

Tags: c#, csv, ssis

Buen día.

Estoy trabajando con archivos CSV y lo estoy leyendo con C#, el CSV tiene como delimitador al `;`, todo bien, pero hay casos donde el dato me llega de esta forma,

> dato1;dato2;"dato3.1;dato3.2";dato4

y el detalle es que al leer el CSV el `;` que se encuentra entre `dato3.1` y `dato3.2` los separa, cuando en realidad es un solo dato, hay alguna forma de obviar los `;` que se encuentren entre `""`.

Sería fácil cambiar el delimitador `;` por un `|`, pero lo ideal sería no cambiar el delimitador.

Me explico mejor, estoy usando la herramienta SSIS para insertar datos en mi BD desde un CSV.

Así se ve en forma de excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si lo abro como texto plano lo veo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el C# lo uso para poder traer las rutas de los archivos CSV que se dejan en un archivo de configuración `.ini` y lo que intenté fue que con C# transformar esos `;` que se encuentran entre `""` a otro elemento de tal manera que el SSIS no me los separe al momento de insertarlos en mi BD

Comment: Realmente ese CSV tiene dos delimitadores: uno es `;` para los campos, y otro es `"`, sólo para delimitar *strings*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la configuracion que se hace en SSIS define el archivo CSV como delimitado por (;) y selecciona la opcion de calificador de texto con el simbolo comillas dobles ("), deberia tomarte todo lo que esta entre esas comillas como un unico campo.

Comment: Como tenía el Data Tools en inglés no me percaté y se encontraba como "Text Qualifier" y este estaba en none, gracias por el Dato, funcionó.

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudar

Answer (score 3):

Tal vez tu respuesta no sea hacer un split simple, si no con una expresion regular?

Para ello, en lugar de usar [String.Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#definition), usas una [expresion regular](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#regular-expressions)

Entonces en tu codigo, el string de captura deberia ser:

```
string Captura = ";(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))";
```

y para recorrer la salida harias algo asi:

```
foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in 
  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(TuCadena, Captura ))
```

y en `m` tendrias cada pedazo de tu linea.

Answer (score 0):

No corte el archivos usando un `Split()` hay mejores formas de procesarlo, utiliza librerias como ser

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

o

[FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/)

con ambos podras configurar como mapean las propiedades de la class que definas a los datos del archivos

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Customer
{
   public int CustId;
   public string Name;
 }

var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Customer>();
var result = engine.ReadFile("FileIn.txt");
```